# Factorization of Artinian ring by its nilradical

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-verification

Theorem. Let $R$ be a commutative Artinian ring with 1 over a field $k$ and $\mathfrak n$ be its nil radical. If char $k \ne 2$ then $R/\mathfrak n$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of fields.
My proof. $R/\mathfrak n$ is also an Artin ring over a field $k$. The image of $k$ under factorization is isomorphic to $k$ because $k$ doesn't contain any nilpotents, so we can multiply elements of $R/\mathfrak n$ by elements of $k$. Dimension of $R/\mathfrak n$ over $k$ is finite because if $\{e_i\}$ is a finite basis of $R$ over $k$ then $\{e_i+\mathfrak n\}$ will be a finite generating set for $R/\mathfrak n$. The ring $R/\mathfrak n$ doesn't contain any non-zero nilpotents - if it had a nilpotent $x+\mathfrak n$ then $x^m+\mathfrak n = 0+\mathfrak n$ for some $m$. That means that $x^m\in \mathfrak n$, so $x^{mk}=0$ for some $k$ $\Rightarrow$ $x\in \mathfrak n$ ,i.e. $x+\mathfrak n=0+\mathfrak n$. That all means that $R/\mathfrak n$ is a semisimple Artin ring $\Rightarrow$ it is a direct sum of fields.
That proof seems right but where the condition that char $k\ne 2$ should be used?

Comment: Why do you say $R$ is finite-dimensional over $k$? What if $R = K$ where $K$ is a field with infinite degree over $k$?

Comment: @user204305: $R$ is an Artin ring, it is finite-dimensional by definition.

Comment: The theorem has nothing to do with the characteristic of $k$: $R/\mathfrak n$ is a reduced artinian ring, so a direct product of fields.

Comment: @user26857: Would something have changed if $R$ wasn't commutative?

Comment: Then $R$ would be a direct product of skew fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nilradical and the Jacobson radical of an Artinian commutative ring coincide, because the Jacobson radical is nilpotent, in particular nil (every element is nilpotent).

Thus the nilradical $\mathfrak{n}$ is a (finite) intersection of maximal ideals, which are pairwise coprime:
$$
\mathfrak{n}=\bigcap_{i=1}^r\mathfrak{m}_i.
$$
By the Chinese remainder theorem,
$$
R/\mathfrak{n}\cong\prod_{i=1}^r R/\mathfrak{m}_i
$$
is a direct product of field.

There's no restriction on the characteristic.

If $R$ is an algebra over an algebraically closed field $k$, then $R/\mathfrak{m}_i\cong k$.

Comment: Why is the nilradical a finite intersection of maximal ideals? Did you mean that every Artinian ring has a finite number of maximal ideals?

Comment: @AnnaAbasheva In a commutative artinian rings there's a finite number of maximal ideals. But this is not needed: since it is Artinian, any ideal that is the intersection of a family of ideals will be the intersection of a finite number of them.